# Spring-Integration AggregatingMessageHandler.setGroupTimeoutExpression visibility

Tags: spring-integration, aggregator

My business logic needs to be able to change configured group timeout on a aggregator.

The code looks like this:

```
@Autowired
AggregatingMessageHandler messageAggregator;

public void setTimeout(Integer timeoutValue) {
    Expression timeoutExpression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(timeoutValue.toString());
    messageAggregator.setGroupTimeoutExpression(timeoutExpression);
}
```

The problem is:

- I want to show the current value to the user, but...
- The [getter is protected](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/aggregator/AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.html#getGroupTimeoutExpression--).

Possible solution scenarios:

- Should I inject an expression on this bean and then change its value,

  - meaning, it will the reevaluate the expression with a new result the next time it builds a message group?
- Should I extend the AggregatingMessageHandler with my own handler that has a public setter?
- Or this is a bug and should be fixed on a next release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you call it as a bug, but your requirement isn't standard.

Let's try to come up with some solution together!

Since you are going to change `group-timeout` at runtime and you really don't need an `expression`, bacause your value is just `Integer`, you can use `org.springframework.integration.expression.ValueExpression` as a `value` of the `AtomicReference` bean.

In this case you can simply show the `current value to the user`:

```
@Autowired
private AtomicReference<ValueExpression> groupTimeoutExpression;

....
   this.groupTimeoutExpression.get().getValue();
```

And use that `AtomicReference` with a new `ValueExpression` for the current value and set the last one to the `AggregatingMessageHandler`.

On the application startup you should do the same for initial `group-timeout`. Or just copy/paste your `value` to the `group-timeout` attribute of the `<aggregator>` and for the `AtomicReference` bean.

HTH

Comment: But I do not want to extend the AggregatingMessageHandler. By the way, I am instantiating it through the context.xml as <int:aggregator .../>

Comment: But I didn't say to `extends AggregatingMessageHandler`. I just pointed out to use `ValueExpression` at runtime and utilize `AtomicReference` to provide a hook to expose the current `group-timeout` value to the end-user. You can continue to use `setGroupTimeoutExpression` without extension. Sorry if  I wasn't clear.